# Call function where argument is a (sub)select statement

Tags: postgresql, subquery, set-returning-functions

My function takes an `int4` as argument and returns a table:

```
SELECT * FROM test_function(545421); -- works fine

SELECT * FROM test_function(SELECT customerid
                            FROM tableX where id = 1); -- syntax error
```

How can I make this work?
Server PostgreSQL 9.3.1

Comment: I think you need an extra pair of parentheses: `SELECT * FROM test_function((SELECT customerid FROM tableX where id = 1))`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### 1. Subquery expression

You can fix it with parentheses like [@a_horse commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97903/call-function-where-argument-is-a-subselect-statement#comment176528_97903):

```
SELECT * FROM test_function((SELECT customerid FROM tableX where id = 1));
```

But this form is error-prone. Nothing in the code guarantees that the subquery only returns a single row. We don't know whether `id` is unique and neither does Postgres (unless it looks up system catalogs). We have to rely on it and hope it won't break.

We could add `LIMIT 1` to be sure, but then we probably should also add `ORDER BY` to get a deterministic pick ...

#### 2. SRF function in the `SELECT` list

You *can* put the **s**et-**r**eturning **f**unction call in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT test_function(customerid) FROM tablex WHERE id = 1;
```

But that has a number of implications:

1. Basics here:

   - [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864815/939860)
2. Also works if the suquery returns multiple rows - and executes the function as many times, appending results to a single result set.
3. If the subquery returns no row, the function is not called at all - while the first syntax variant converts "no row" to a NULL value and calls the function with that input.
4. If the function returns a single column, that's decomposed automatically and you get a resultset with that column.
5. If the function returns more than one column, you still get a resultset with a single column, being a *record*.
   You can wrap that in a subquery and decompose in an outer `SELECT`:

   ```
   SELECT (f).* FROM (
      SELECT test_function(customerid) AS f FROM tablex WHERE id = 1
      ) sub;
   ```

   You *could* even decompose immediately:

   ```
   SELECT (test_function(customerid)).* FROM tablex WHERE id = 1;
   ```

   But that's the one form to **avoid**, because Postgres currently (Postgres 15) still has a weak spot there and ends up calling the function once per decomposed column. Needlessly expensive, and may have undesirable effects - think of volatile functions or side-effects nested in the function. See:

   - [How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18370271/939860)

#### 3. [`JOIN LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL)

The modern, explicit syntax for this is a `LATERAL` join (since Postgres **9.3**):

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM   tableX t, test_function(t.customerid) f
WHERE  t.id = 1;
```

Which is short syntax for:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM   tableX t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL test_function(t.customerid) f
WHERE  t.id = 1;
```

Same result as with the first form (your fixed original), except for **subtle but possibly important differences**:

If `tableX` has **no row** for `t.id = 1`, the **function in the `LATERAL` join** is never called, and the query returns nothing (no row).
If, on the other hand, a row is found for `t.id = 1` and that has `customerid IS NULL`, then the function is called with `NULL` input and we get whatever the function returns for `NULL`.
*That's typically how it should be.*

Your (fixed) original form with the **subquery expression** cannot distinguish between these two cases. "No row" results in the same NULL value as `customerid` being `NULL`. The function is called with `NULL` input either way.
*That's typically *not* how it should be.*

The `LATERAL` query also does not break if `id` is not unique. And you can easily return additional columns from `tableX` if you want.

So option *3.* is clearly my favorite.

Comment: One other benefit of `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` is that it handles invocations of the function over multiple rows of a result set, whereas the subquery expression can handle at most a single row, otherwise it will produce `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`. Also, the short form of the expression may produce `ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "t"` if additional tables are joined.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - First, your answers are invaluable, and have helped me frequently - thank you.  Second - in this question, I'm getting a little confused at the end with the "subtle but possibly important difference" - could you clarify which "form" is the reference in the two bullet points?

Comment: @Randall: Yeah, wasn't all that clear. I clarified a bit.