# How to execute a trigger procedure with an expression as an argument?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, parameter

How can I pass an expression as an argument when calling a trigger function?

```
create trigger my_trigger
after insert on my_table
for each row
execute function trigger_job(
    'job_name',
    (json_build_object(
       'foo', current_setting('foo', true),
       'bar', current_setting('bar', true)
    ))
);
```

I know [how](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97903/call-function-where-argument-is-a-subselect-statement) to call a "normal" function with an expression as an argument, but I can't get it to work calling a function from the trigger. I also know how to read the passed arguments from TG_ARGV[] in the trigger function, but that's beyond this question.

I also tried something simple like:

```
create trigger my_trigger
after insert on my_table
for each row
execute function trigger_job(
    'job_name',
    (true)
);
```

But I still get the error:

> `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("`
>
> `LINE 6:                 (true)`
>
> `^`

Update: I am now using an intermediate function. The trigger calls the intermediate function with the single text parameter. That intermediate function builds the second argument and calls the final `trigger_job` function with both arguments. Simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be done.  From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html):

> The arguments are literal string constants